# How to read array element (json) in Angular

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs

I have a var called `$scope.informationData` and the contents (as output by console.log) is like this:

```
{"completed":100,"pending":50,"defects":20,"overdue":10}
```

If I, in my HTML, use this though:

```
<div class="huge">{{ informationData.overdue }}</div>
```

Then it's empty. I don't think there's anything wrong with the binding though because if I do `{{ informationData }}` then it outputs the same JSON as above.

I think I'm just using the wrong syntax to read the data - what do I need to change `informationData.overdue` to in order to see the number 10 appear?

Comment: change your json like this:: {"completed":"100","pending":"50","defects":"20","overdue":"10"}

Comment: It's working http://plnkr.co/edit/1JwgXFFPoFSqAWuMPAIp?p=preview

Comment: what you get when printing whole object `{{ informationData }}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Deserialize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson) the json

```
$scope.informationData = angular.fromJson($scope.informationData);
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your value in quotes not your keys.
Change your json like this::

```
{"completed":"100","pending":"50","defects":"20","overdue":"10"}
```

Or

```
{completed:"100",pending:"50",defects:"20",overdue:"10"}
```